# Does this quote by Martial really exist?

Tags: quote-source, latin-language

On Wikipedia I came across a quote by Tacitus which says:

> To ravage, to slaughter, to usurp under false titles, they call empire;
>  
>   and where they make a desert, they call it peace.

From my school days I remember a very similar quote by Martial, but after more than two decades and some relocations my old textbook is lost. I wanted to find out about it, but on the internet there's no trace of it so I have to rely on my memories. I remember that the textbook said that Martial beside the Epigrams wrote a minor epic poem. In that poem a Barbarian chief before a battle with the Romans addressed his tribe and said:

> They rape, they kill, they plunder, they burn
>   they leave a desert and they call it peace

Actually I prefer the supposed Martial's version, the translation has a stronger rhythm. Did he really write it? Is there any reference somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Tacitus's [*Agricola*](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/9090/pg9090-images.html) says, at the end of XXX:

> XXX. "... Auferre, trucidare, rapere, falsis nominibus imperium; atque, ubi solitudinem faciunt, pacem appellant."

which [is to say](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/7524/7524-h/7524-h.htm)

> To ravage, to slaughter, to usurp under false titles, they call empire; and where they make a desert, they call it peace.

It might be possible that Martial wrote something along the same lines, and that Tacitus borrowed Martial's simile, but Google has not helped me verify this.

Comment: It's true that my memory might be wrong, but I don't rule out that Tacitus plagiarised Martial. In that period senators where still trying to resist the recently established role of the emperor, so a lot of them were keen to mock the imperial propaganda.

Comment: BTW I knew that Google couldn't help on this, I did a lot of searches on Google, Wikipedia, Metager, Qwant and so on before posting this question.

Comment: Only in my old, now lost, textbook.

Comment: Why do you think I posted this question? If the answer required just some googling there would have been no need to post it.

Comment: I don't mean to offend you; of course you Googled as you stated. I do not wish to argue with you;  I do wish you good luck in finding resolution to your question.  I will delete my earlier comments.

Comment: I didn't take your earlier answers as an offence. I just replied this way because I'm worried by the attitude "if it's not on google then it probably doesn't exist". Google is not perfect and an over reliance on it might be dangerous.